# position a div on the right of another div in ionic HTML

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i want to position a div with the id "first" to the right of another div with the id "second" how to do that ?

```
 <ion-col>
         <div id="second">
          <ion-img src="./assets/images/from_to.svg" style="height:30%;width:10%;"></ion-img>
         </div>
        <div id="first">
        <ion-label>Domicile</ion-label>
        <ion-label >120 Square de la Couronne,Paris</ion-label>
        </div>
 </ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you lessen the use of the basic html, for example, try using  instead of .
Second, you practically never use id with html tags.
Now to answer your question, a little bit more code would help but here's one solution:

**HTML:**

```
    <ion-col>
  <ion-item class="second">
    <ion-image class="img" src="/assets/images/from_to.svg" />
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="first">
    <ion-label>Domicile</ion-label>
    <ion-label>120 Square de la Couronne,Paris</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

**CSS:**

```
.first{
float: right;
}
.second{
float:left;
}
```

I assume that you already know that "HTML" goes to your x.page.html and the "CSS" goes to your x.page.scss of the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create a list containing an image with an description on the right side on every element. If that's the case try `ion-list` which offers interacting with the list elements much easier, since you can use the included swiping, dragging within the list, and deleting items.

[image]

**Example:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
            <ion-img src="./assets/images/from_to.svg"></ion-img>
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
            <h2>Domicile</h2>
            <p>120 Square de la Couronne,Paris</p>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
           <ion-img src="./assets/images/from_to.svg"></ion-img>
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
            <h2>Domicile</h2>
            <p>120 Square de la Couronne,Paris</p>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```